# J2ME, Xml Response from Http Post Method

Tags: java-me

This is my **Response String from HTTP Post Method**

```
1)  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Open</string>

2)  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Close</string>
```

But I want only the Selected Or Result String from above lines

like from 1 response) I only want **Open**
     from 2 response) I only want **Close**

How I can get this.

please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your handset supports JSR 172 you can follow [this example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/JSR_172%3a_XML_Parsing_Example) to parse the data out.  Otherwise you will need to write your own rudimentary string splitting/tokenizing.  If you can guarantee the data is always in the format you've given, it won't be very hard.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [kXML2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/) xml parsing api